# No module named bidi.algorithm

Tags: python, module, arabic

I download this lib: `python-bidi` [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-bidi), run it with:

```
python setup.py test
```

in my cmd, I have python 2.7 but i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\CLIENT\Desktop\IMPLEMENTATION\Affichage.py", line 31, in    <module>
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
ImportError: No module named bidi.algorithm
```

Answer (score 27):

You should install python-bidi using this command:

```
easy_install python-bidi
```

or

```
pip install python-bidi
```